# volume preserving homeomorphism between piecewise linear integral structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, smooth-manifolds

Assume that X and Y both have piecewise linear integral structures. Let f : X → Y be a piecewise linear homeomorphism such that

• V-1: f (t · x) = t · f (x), and

• V-2: x ∈ X is integral if and only if f (x) is integral in Y.

Then f is volume preserving.

how can i prove it? is it any classical proposition?

Comment: What kind of objects are X and Y? The "multiplication by t" does not make sense in general.

Comment: X and Y are piecewise linear manifolds and t is a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that f is volume preserving, we only need to show that each of its linear pieces is volume preserving.  So, it’s a property of linear maps.
If a linear map $f:R^n \to R^n$ sends integer points to integer points, it must have integer coefficients. Because of the “only if” part of the hypothesis, its inverse also has integer coefficients. Therefore, its determinant is equal to +1 or -1, and f is consequently volume preserving.